# How to compare 2 list where string matches element in alternate list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Hi I'm in the process of learning so you may have to bear with me. I have 2 lists I'd like to compare whilst keeping any matches and append them whilst appending any non matches to another output list. 
Heres my code:

```
def EntryToFieldMatch(Entry, Fields):
    valid = []
    invalid = []
    for c in Entry:
        count = 0
        for s in Fields:
            count +=1
            if s in c:
                valid.append(c)
            elif count == len(Entry):
                invalid.append(s)
                Fields.remove(s)



    print valid
    print "-"*50
    print invalid


def main():
    vEntry = ['27/04/2014', 'Hours = 28', 'Site = Abroad', '03/05/2015', 'Date = 28-04-2015', 'Travel = 2']
    Fields = ['Week_Stop', 'Date', 'Site', 'Hours', 'Travel', 'Week_Start', 'Letters']
    EntryToFieldMatch(vEntry, Fields)

if __name__ = "__main__":
    main()
```

the output seems fine except its not returning all the fields in the 2 output lists. This is the output I receive:

```
['Hours = 28', 'Site = Abroad', 'Date = 28-04-2015', 'Travel = 2']
--------------------------------------------------
['Week_Start', 'Letters']
```

I just have no idea why the second list doesn't include "Week_Stop". I've run the debugger and followed the code through a few times to no avail. I've read about sets but I didn't see any way to return fields that match and discard fields that don't.
Also im open to suggestion's if anybody knows of a way to simplify this whole process, I'm not asking for free code, just a nod in the right direction. 
Python 2.7, Thanks

Comment: it is a little unclear what the outputs should be. 1) valid entries 2) invalid entries or missed fields?

Comment: `count == len(Entry)` makes zero sense to me. Should that be `count == len(Fields)` maybe?

Comment: Looking at it now, it should have been done in one of the ways shown below, at the time my thinking was that if there were more entries then fields that some entries would go unchecked when all the fields were sorted out. This is probably specific to my case but Entry will always have more elements then Fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have two conditions, either it is in the string or the count is equal to the length of Entry, neither of which catch the first element `'Week_Stop'`, the length goes from 7-6-5 catching `Week_Start` but never gets to `0` so you never reach `Week_Stop`.

A more efficient way would be to use sets or a [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want to keep order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def EntryToFieldMatch(Entry, Fields):
    valid = []
    # create orderedDict from the words in Fields
    # dict lookups are 0(1)
    st = OrderedDict.fromkeys(Fields)
    # iterate over Entry
    for word in Entry:
        # split the words once on whitespace
        spl = word.split(None, 1)
        # if the first word/word appears in our dict keys
        if spl[0] in st:
            # add to valid list
            valid.append(word)
            # remove the key
            del st[spl[0]]
    print valid
    print "-"*50
    # only invalid words will be left
    print st.keys()
```

Output:

```
['Hours = 28', 'Site = Abroad', 'Date = 28-04-2015', 'Travel = 2']
--------------------------------------------------
['Week_Stop', 'Week_Start', 'Letters']
```

For large lists this would be significantly faster than your quadratic approach. Having `0(1)` dict lookups means your code goes from quadratic to linear, every time you do `in Fields` that is an `0(n)` operation.

Using a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) the approach is similar:

```
def EntryToFieldMatch(Entry, Fields):
    valid = []
    st = set(Fields)
    for word in Entry:
        spl = word.split(None,1)
        if spl[0] in st:
            valid.append(word)
            st.remove(spl[0])
    print valid
    print "-"*50
    print st
```

The difference using sets is order is not maintained.

Comment: So would your second solution be faster then mpolednik's solution? Order not being a critical factor.

Comment: @SidSpace, yes for any reasonable input size sets are far more efficient, linear is always going to scale a hell of a lot better than quadratic. The only extra cost bar a loop over Entry is building the set/dict which is a linear operation

Comment: Seeing as this is seems like a more computable solution, l will put this as the correct answer. Also sorry about the down-voting im not sure why this is happening

Comment: @SidSpace, no worries, pick whatever answer suits you best but it is important to know the difference between a quadratic and linear solution, dicts and sets can help make your code very efficient.

Comment: Is this some sort of bug? I'm sure its not me, its saying i don't even have access to voting yet

Comment: @SidSpace, no prob, I know it is not you, it happens on SO, you nor I should lose any sleep over it, there is nothing wrong with this answer, in fact it is  very efficient solution, there are just some knobheads on SO at times much like the rest of the world ;)

Answer (score -1):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def EntryToFieldMatch(Entries, Fields):

    # using list comprehension 
    # (typically they go on one line, but they can be multiline 
    #  so they look more like their for loop equivalents)
    valid = [entry for entry in Entries
                 if any([field in entry 
                         for field in Fields])]

    invalidEntries = [entry for entry in Entries 
                          if not any([field in entry 
                                      for field in Fields])]

    missedFields = [field for field in Fields
                          if not any([field in entry 
                                      for entry in Entries])]

    print 'valid entries:', valid
    print '-' * 80
    print 'invalid entries:', invalidEntries
    print '-' * 80
    print 'missed fields:', missedFields

vEntry = ['27/04/2014', 'Hours = 28', 'Site = Abroad', '03/05/2015', 'Date = 28-04-2015', 'Travel = 2']
Fields = ['Week_Stop', 'Date', 'Site', 'Hours', 'Travel', 'Week_Start', 'Letters']
EntryToFieldMatch(vEntry, Fields)
```

---

```
valid entries: ['Hours = 28', 'Site = Abroad', 'Date = 28-04-2015', 'Travel = 2']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
invalid entries: ['27/04/2014', '03/05/2015']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
missed fields: ['Week_Stop', 'Week_Start', 'Letters']
```

Comment: i think you may have misread the post, The expected outcome should be the same for your valid list, but in the invalid list there should only be the Fields that didn't match up to anything in "Entry". Eg "Week_Stop", "Week_Start" & "Letters". I do like the approach though.Also sorry about the down-voting im not sure why this is happening

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was unclear in the question, I added a comment to clarify and edited my answer to include both...